# JAVA Auto message sender

Tags: discord-jda

I want to write a program that will send a message from my account to the discord server every 30 minutes. But when I run the program, I get an error 401. It is important for me that the message be sent without the use of bots, namely from my account.

I have 401 error with this

```
package org.example;

import discord4j.common.util.Snowflake;
import discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder;
import discord4j.core.GatewayDiscordClient;
import discord4j.core.object.entity.channel.TextChannel;
import discord4j.core.object.entity.User;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

class DiscordApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String token = "My User token"; //
        Snowflake channelId = Snowflake.of("ID"); // ID

        GatewayDiscordClient client = DiscordClientBuilder.create(token)
                .build()
                .login()
                .block();

        User self = client.getSelf().block();
        if (self != null) {
            Mono<TextChannel> channelMono = client.getChannelById(channelId)
                    .cast(TextChannel.class);

            channelMono.flatMap(channel -> channel.createMessage("My Message"))
                    .subscribe();
        }

        client.onDisconnect().block();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sending messages from a user account is against the terms of service and thus likely unsupported by all libraries.